# Visual Studio 2019 asking to acknowledge Apple's Apple ID and Privacy Statement

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, apple-id

I have looked at other questions similar to this, but I can't find anything to resolve this.
Windows 10 Pro
Visual Studio 2019 v. 16.7.6
I probably don't have the absolute latest version, because we don't like making any changes this close to a production publish.
All our provisioning profiles expired last week, so I downloaded everything new onto the Mac and ran them in XCode. All the AdHoc profiles work just fine.
For some reason, I could not see my App Store provisioning profile, or even the Apple Distribution Signing Identity, so after several attempts to fix that, I went to Tools->Options->Xamarin->Apple Accounts, and clicked on my appleid. That's when I initially got the message: "Need to acknowledge to Apple's Apple ID and Privacy statement."
I logged in to appleid.apple.com, but I can't find anything to acknowledge.
Thinking something might be wrong, I deleted the account from VS 2019 and tried to recreate it.
Now there just is no account at all, and trying to add it gets the same error message.
I am not, and do not, want to enable 2 factor on my account, and I am thinking this is Apple's way of trying to force me to do that, but I am not certain of that.

Comment: You could post the issue to **Help->Send Feedback->Report s problem** .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT When I try to do that, the developercommunity site gives me an empty "Unexpected Error" popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this has to do with 2 factor. Once I enabled 2 factor on my Apple ID, everything worked.